# What's the difference between the NVIDIA v304.xx and the v173.xx driver branches?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I know the question has nothing to do with Ubuntu directly, but I'm trying to decide what driver to use. I can't seem to google my way to victory today and I figured this community would be the next best place to ask.

NVIDIA lists the following:

- Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver v173.1437 was released on
  April 5, 2013.
- Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver v304.88 was released on April 2, 2013.

v304 can't be just a beta branch, because NVIDIA also explicitly labels the beta versions with the word "beta" in red.

So what is it?

Comment: Would this answer your question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/97373/what-is-the-difference-between-nvidia-driver-version-173-and-version-current

Comment: @BrunoPereira Yeah, I guess it helps, thanks. I came across that earlier when searching, but I didn't know what "nvidia-current" meant. I thought it might mean the same thing, but didn't want to jump to conclusions. Guess current refers to the branch with the highest version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 173.xx branch is, as far as I know, the old legacy driver branch. It is a driver specifically for older hardware (below the GeForce 8000 series video cards). The 300 series drivers are the current stable drivers and are the recommended choice for the GeForce 8000 and higher cards. These drivers normally provide the best performance, optimization and support.

Comment: So if I'm offered a choice of either legacy branch or current branch, I should take current? Example: My particular "card" is GeForce 6150SE nForce 430, and the driver page offers both legacy and current versions, so I didn't know which to pick. I wasn't even aware one was legacy and one was current. Thanks!

Comment: If your card is supported by the most current driver than its most likely the best choice, yes. :) If you aren't sure, you can always check Nvidia's driver page. All supported products of their drivers are listed there. ;) http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Comment: Usually your card will be *either* supported by the current driver *or* the legacy driver.  I think it would be rare to have a choice.  The reason Nvidia maintain legacy drivers is so they can drop support for old hardware in their newer drivers.  You'll probably find that if you install the 304 drivers it may appear to work but without hardware support you won't get graphical acceleration.